# How to write two replace functions in one select statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to replace two things in one select statement. Now I can replace one character at a time. But as per my requirment, I need to replace two things in one statement.I want to replace one special character by Zero and another is this data is stored in multiple lines. I want to fetch this data in one line.

```
select replace(message,chr(ACII_Value),0) 
from my_table -- I can replace special character by zero using this.

select (message,chr(10),' ') 
from my_table -- I can put all data in single line using this.
```

Now I want to do this in one select statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select replace( replace( message, chr(ACII_Value), 0), chr(10), ' ') 
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is the [TRANSLATE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions216.htm#i1501659) function:

```
select translate(message, chr(ASCII_Value)||chr(10), '0 ') from my_table;
```

Although if you're only replacing two characters, I'd go with @schurik's answer since it uses a simpler, more common function.